# fopen failes even if the script, the parent folder and the target file, all are owned by same user

Tags: php, permissions, fopen

Even if safe mode is activated on the server, if script file, target file and parent folder is owned by the same user, fopen should work without any problem. Any ideas why this is happening?
The files have 755 permission.
Thank you for your time and effort.

```
$filename="file.html";
echo "Current User: ".get_current_user()."; UID: ".getmyuid()."; GID: ".getmygid()."<br/>";
echo "Current PID: ". getmypid() . "<br/>";
echo "Parent folder owner: ". fileowner(".") . "<br/>";
echo "$filename owner: " . fileowner($filename) . "<br/>";
echo "Current folder is writable: " . is_writable($filename);
```

OUTPUT:

> Current User: vnnamp; UID: 32024; GID: 32026 
>   Parent folder owner: 32024
>   file.html owner: 32024 
>   Current folder is writable: false

Comment: It clearly says: `Current folder is writable: false`

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to know. If everything is owned by the same user, why isn't it writable... Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your script is operating in the correct directory?

If it is not then the file name you pass it likely doesn't exist and that would be why `is_writable()` returns false.  Use `getcwd()`  to print out the directory the script is operating in (can set it with `chdir()`) or use absolute file names.

EDIT: Just to summarize the discussion below:

- Try absolute path name: Nope
- Check open-basedir in php.ini and httpd.conf: Nope
- Try prefixing path with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`: Nope
- getmyuid() returns script file owner not process owner
  check mismatch file owner and process user with
  `posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())`: Yes, cause of the problem

Comment: Yes, the file do exist as I get a permission denied error when I do an fopen on the file...

Comment: Try absolute pathname?  /var/www/sitename/htdocs/mydir/myfile.html or similar?

Comment: Tried the absolute path just now but the result is the same: Warning: fopen(/home/vnnamp/public_html/vishnu/sl/file.html) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in <script_path>

Comment: What is open-basedir http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir set to in php.ini or httpd.conf?  You won't be able to work on files out side of its setting.

Comment: In phpinfo() I can see this against the column "Local Value": /home/vnnamp:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp. So I guess that too is not a problem...

Comment: I'm out of ideas sorry mate. :S

Comment: I get the same values when I use ini_get('open_basedir'). So its has not been set anywhere else... Thank you...

Comment: Heh I couldn't let it rest found this snippet on phpnet: I had to switch from relative paths to full paths when my web host recently migrated the server onto their hosting cloud.  This used to work for me:

<?php
$fplog = fopen('ipn.log','a');
?>

After the migration, however, I received the following error message:

Warning: fopen(ipn.log) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\home\server_name\log_test.php on line 21

I had to change the code to the following to get it to work:

<?php
$logfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\\ipn.log';
$fplog = fopen($logfile,'a');
?>

Comment: No.. that too does not work... I think the problem is that the user the PHP is running under does not have permission to write to this folder/file.

Comment: Hope that's it. I'd of thought getmyuid() would return the php user though.

Comment: For getmyuid() php.net says: Gets the user ID of the current script. So I am now confused if it is the owner of the file in which the script is running or it is the user under which PHP is running...

Comment: Another php.net snippet: to get the username of the process owner (rather than the file owner), you can use:

<?php
$processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
print $processUser['name'];
?>

Comment: Confirmed. PHP is running under user id 99. So thats the problem I am facing here... With the safe mode ON, 99 is compared with the owner of file and it fails. So fopen fails.... I think this is what is happening. Thank you John, discussions with you lead to this... From php.net: Note that this function really does what the description says, it returns the numeric user id of the user who *owns the file* containing the current script not the effective user id of user *running* the current script.  Most applications will want the latter which is provided by posix_getuid().

Comment: Tricky naming, I had no idea about the posix_geteuid. Glad it's solved now. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the user is the owner of the file, it does not mean file should be writable by the user. It may have permissions like 0444 or so.

Answer (score 0):

The result of is_writable() function is cached. Try clearing it with `clearstatcache()`

Comment: In my original script I am using fopen directly without is_writable. Above script is only to show the owner of all related file/folder.